# What is the "local" keyword used for?

Tags: c++, c, keyword

I assume the `local` keyword is similar to the `static` keyword, but not sure.  I'm not able to find much info on this keyword.  For example, I've seen code that declares

```
local inline int jump()
{
    ....
}
```

What does the `local` keyword do and is it much different from `static`?  I haven't seen this keyword used much.

Comment: There is no such keyword in C or C++.  Perhaps this is an extension someone invented just for your programming environment.

Comment: I don't see nothing particularly wrong with this question

Comment: Here is a list of all c/c++ keywords https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keywordcreate

Comment: C11 introduced the keyword [`_Thread_local`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1). Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Could be something defined with `typedef`?

Comment: Somewhere in a header there could be a `#define local` macro. It might be conditional (in a `#if` block) and have different definitions depending on compiler flags. A `#define local static` would possibly be one of them.

Comment: @JardelLucca it's wrong on saying "I've seen code that declares" **without provide where**. We cannot simply guess what's it is and answer on that.

Comment: #eglease I don't think so, it should not compile :( it seems more related with `#define`: i.e. https://github.com/madler/spoof/blob/master/spoof.c#L232

Comment: @JardelLucca I don't see anything wrong with this question, either.  I don't think it should have been downvoted, and I don't think it should have been closed.  Unfortunately, the old adage "There's no such thing as a stupid question" is **not** true on SO.  There are questions which (often quite unfairly) are deemed "stupid", and such questions do get downvoted and closed, through no fault of the people asking them.

Comment: @appleapple It's not necessary to know where the code came from to answer "There is no such keyword in C or C++".

Comment: @SteveSummit that doesn't answer the question. And is already provided in first comment.

Comment: @appleapple The question as stated can't be answered, because it contains a false premise.  But that's a common enough occurrence.

Comment: @SteveSummit true so downvote and close it. Just a note, I do follow most question I downvote so I can catch up their update.

Comment: @appleapple Indeed the answer is already provided in the first comment -- and someone was able to provide it even though the source hadn't been identified.  So what you were complaining about?

Comment: @SteveSummit are you saying ["it cannot be answered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699039/what-is-the-local-keyword-used-for?noredirect=1#comment123198349_69699039) and ["the answer is already provided in the first comment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699039/what-is-the-local-keyword-used-for?noredirect=1#comment123198366_69699039) at the same time?

Comment: I don't have access to all the code, but that makes sense why I haven't seen this keyword.  Thanks.

Comment: @appleapple Yes I am, and I'm done here.

Comment: @SteveSummit oh and just in case, I don't downvote.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well you're contradicting yourself. And 1. hover over downvote: "it's unclear or not useful". And 2. "close: "Needs details or clarity" (at least by me). It's clearly done correctly IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the keywords reference.  I should have checked that first.

Comment: I ended up here after seeing a bunch of functions declared `local`, e.g. `local void fill_window()` in a C zip library...in zip.h, they had used `#define local static`, presumably on the premise that `local` was easier to read.